# AngularJS: Add toggle function to an image inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat for div element. I have a toggle function on image inside div element. However, when I click on image, function gets triggered but it is showing up same data for all divs. Below is the code.

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>
        <img src="img/icon1.png" class="pull-right" ng-click="showDiv(item.itemId,$index)">
    </div>
    <div ng-show="hiddenDiv[$index]">
        <div ng-repeat="student in studentData">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <div>{{student.name}}</div>
                    <div>{{student.adress}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$scope.hiddenDiv=[];
$scope.showDiv=function(itemId,index) {
    $scope.hiddenDiv[index] = !$scope.hiddenDiv[index];
    var myResult = ListService.getList(url here);
    myResult.then(function (data) {
        if(data && data.list)
            $scope.studentData = data.list;
    });
}
```

Here, I am using same scope variable in all divs inside ng-repeat.

**Updated Answer :**

**js :**

```
$scope.studentData = [];
$scope.studentData[index] = data.list;
```

**HTML :**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have unique students for every item, you need to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>
        <img src="img/icon1.png" class="pull-right" ng-click="showDiv(item.itemId,$index)">
    </div>
    <div ng-show="hiddenDiv[$index]">
        <div ng-repeat="student in item.studentData">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <div>{{student.name}}</div>
                    <div>{{student.adress}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$scope.hiddenDiv=[];
$scope.showDiv=function(itemId,index) {
    $scope.hiddenDiv[index] = !$scope.hiddenDiv[index];
    var myResult = ListService.getList(url here);
    myResult.then(function (data) {
        if(data && data.list)
            $scope.items[index].studentData = data.list;
    });
}
```

or use the same as for hiddenDiv

```
$scope.hiddenDiv=[];
$scope.studentData = [];
$scope.showDiv=function(itemId,index) {
    $scope.hiddenDiv[index] = !$scope.hiddenDiv[index];
    var myResult = ListService.getList(url here);
    myResult.then(function (data) {
        if(data && data.list)
            $scope.studentData[index].studentData = data.list;
    });
}
```

and html:

```
<div ng-repeat="student in studentData[$index]">
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried, but getting **TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined**. when I click on image.

Comment: Do you have `$scope.items` defined?

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer.